# Alarm set more frequently than time provided

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

Whenever user enters MainActivity I am setting alarm on an interval of 43200000 miliseconds  using code below and also remove previous alarms.

```
int interval =43200000;
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

> Problem is am getting a notification or alarm is fired after every 2 mins i open the app

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you not want to fire notification in 2 minutes?

Comment: after every 43200000 milisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use this:
`manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pendingIntent);`
second parameter:

> triggerAtMillis   long: time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

[manual](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

or better:

`am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP:AlarmManager.RTC, nexttime, pi);`

that is re-fired each time on broadcastreceiver is started and each startup (launch device) event .

43200000 is 12 hours;) do not forget
Futhermore , use long type for each milliseconds variable:
 `long interval = 43200000L;` in order to prevent some bugs.